# Filtro entre 2 fechas por MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Tengo una tabla con 3 datos:

```
INT id
DATE inicio
DATE fin
```

Necesito filtrar para quitar todos los id que entre inicio y fin tengan menos de 1 año.

Intenté utilizar DATEDIFF (SELECT DATEDIFF (`inicio`, `fin`) as `diferencia` FROM `tabla`) y también por TIMESTAMPDIFF (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF (YEAR, `inicio`, `fin`) as `diferencia` FROM `tabla`), pero luego no puedo utilizar "diferencia" para comparar si es mayor o igual a 1 año.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT id, DATEDIFF (`inicio`, `fin`) as `diferencia` FROM `tabla` WHERE `diferencia` >= 1;
```

Me gustaría saber como poder comparar la diferencia de tiempo desde el WHERE y si se puede realizar directamente con inicio y fin sin necesidad de crear diferencia.

Comment: Agrega lo que has intentado

Comment: Agregué el ejemplo de la consulta que estaba intentando realizar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes utilizar alias en el `where` de una consulta SQL por esto no funcionaria lo que tratas de hacer con `diferencia >= 1`. Debes poner la expresion directamente para que funcione. Ejemplo:

```
SELECT id, DATEDIFF (`inicio`, `fin`) as `diferencia` 
FROM `tabla` 
WHERE DATEDIFF (`inicio`, `fin`) >= 1;
```

Comment: Confirmo que tu solución es correcta.